# Filtering Custom List Items

Tags: web-part, custom-list, filter

I created a custom list then I created a webpart for custom list. I edit settings of the webpart. I created a new filter for this list.  I clicked the "Edit Page" then I selected webpart. I edited the webpart's current view as follow.

[image]

But the filter doesn't work. It shows yesterday's items. Rather, it shows first items of the list. Am I doing missing something? Should I do another for filter?

I added filter another page but it doesn't work too. I'm doing filtering by date. The problem may be the reason? I'm using [Today] statement.

[image]

Comment: Is your server's date correct? Maybe it's taking Yesterday's date as Today!

Comment: Server's date is correct @ArsalanAdamKhatri. I checked the bottom right corner of this screen. Where can I check else?

Comment: If you have multiple server environment, check all the servers. Just a wild guess :)

Comment: Can you please clear which Web-Part you are using, are you using a "List View Web-part" or you have created a custom web-part.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri you're right. I checked all the servers for date. I changed time zone and calender settings and this problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your server's date correct? Maybe it's taking Yesterday's date as Today!

If you have multiple server environment, check all the servers.